# How to implement an atomic switch from one IObserver to another?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<byte[]>` that I transform into an `IObservable<XDocument>` using some intermediate steps:

```
var observedXDocuments =
    from b in observedBytes
    // Lot of intermediate steps to transform byte arrays into XDocuments
    select xDoc;
```

At some point in time, I'm interested in the observed `XDocument`s so I subscribe an `IObserver<XDocument>`. At a later point in time, I would like to subscribe another `IObserver<XDocument>` and dispose of the old one.

How can I do this in one atomic operation, without loosing any observed `XDocument`? I could do something like:

```
oldObserver.Dispose();
observedXDocuments.Subscribe(newObserver);
```

I'm worried though, that between these two calls, I could loose an `XDocument`. If I switch the two calls, it could happen that I receive the same `XDocument` twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably add a layer of indirection.  Write a class called ExchangeableObserver, subscribe it to your observable, and keep it permanently subscribed.  The job of ExchangeableObserver is to delegate everything to a given sub-observer.  But the programmer is allowed to change the sub-observer being delegated to at any time.  In my example I have an Exchange() method.  Something like:

```
public class ExchangeableObserver<T> : IObserver<T> {
  private IObserver<T> inner;

  public ExchangeableObserver(IObserver<T> inner) {
    this.inner=inner;
  }

  public IObserver<T> Exchange(IObserver<T> newInner) {
    return Interlocked.Exchange(ref inner, newInner);
  }

  public void OnNext(T value) {
    inner.OnNext(value);
  }

  public void OnCompleted() {
    inner.OnCompleted();
  }

  public void OnError(Exception error) {
    inner.OnError(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Really like this solution. Always a good idea to add additional layers of indirection ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm feeling a little unsure about the reads of "inner" in the OnXXX methods.  I'm wondering if "inner" should have been marked "volatile" so that the field's reads become volatile reads.

Comment: Also unsure whether this is necessary. In theory I think the following sequence could happen: `Thread1: Read inner`, `Thread2: Exchange`, `Thread1: Call inner.OnNext`. Adding volatile won't fix this: it just prevents the compiler or CLR from reordering instructions. I think this implies that access to inner should be guarded using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, for example. I do not think this causes too much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a semaphore that makes shure that while `IObservable<byte[]>` prepares for `IObservable<XDocument>` no observer-change takes place.

pseudocode how this could be done (not testet)

```
  System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim criticalSection 
       = new System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim(...);  


  ... converting from `IObservable<byte[]>` to `IObservable<XDocument>`  
  criticalSection.EnterReadLock();
  Call IObservable<XDocument>
  criticalSection.ExitReadLock();

  .... replacing IObservable<XDocument>
  criticalSection.EnterWriteLock();
  Call change IObservable<XDocument>
  criticalSection.ExitWriteLock();
```

Edit: with `Call IObservable<XDocument>`

```
  > What exactly do you mean with the line `Call IObservable<XDocument>`?
```

I interprete your sentense

```
  > I have an `IObservable<byte[]>` that I transform 
  > into an `IObservable<XDocument>` using some intermediate steps...
```

that you have registered an eventhandler for `IObservable<byte[]>` that creates a `XDocument` from `byte[]` and then calls 
something that triggers an event for `IObservable<XDocument>`.

`Call IObservable<XDocument>` means the code that triggers the followup-event

Comment: You mean that I temporarily stall the pipeline that transforms `byte[]` to `XDocument` while switching observers? I suppose that would work but I'm curious whether this has any performance impact.

Comment: I see you just edited your answer. Not sure I understand how this could work. The `IObservable<XDocument>` keeps pushing `XDocument`s while switching (it's a 'hot' observable). What exactly do you mean with the line `Call IObservable<XDocument>`?